# How to do a non-uniform parallel processing in python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

Is there an efficient way to do a non-uniform parallel processing in python, i.e. when it matters what parallel process/thread is used to process each input entry?

**Example:**
There is a single message queue, which produces tuples `(x,n)`, where `x` is some kind of data and `n` is some indicator of which parallel process/thread is suitable for processing that kind of data. Data processing objects maintain some state, and so one can not just give data to any parallel process, but only can give it to the process, which processed the same type of data last time.

I understand, that one can split the messages into sub-queues first, start parallel python processes and subscribe each of them for its own queue only. But I want to understand if there is a more direct and easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) library to accomplish non-uniform execution but parallel programming concept in high level programming languages not same as described in such languages like c, c++. 
your approach to the problem should be as keeping data in same queue not with subqueues. there should be a [strategy](https://medium.com/@sheikhsajid/design-patterns-in-python-part-1-the-strategy-pattern-54b24897233e)/[adapter](https://medium.com/@mrfksiv/python-design-patterns-04-the-facade-6cfe67033354) design pattern implementation to distribute data to adaptive data processing services as possible in asyncio library.
if you embrace the approach, you should consider implementing your queue as thread safe. it can be as in [native python library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) or extending it with your functional requirements.

remaining part of problem looks like implementing it as producer-consumer with asyncio coroutines

if problem set uses big data you may also consider implementing data processing backend in [apache spark](https://spark.apache.org/)